# Is [code-inspection] useful?

Tags: support, tags

No tag wiki content, no followers, 43 questions tagged, and the content of these questions is all over the place: is [code-inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-inspection) useful?

It is mostly benign, in that it is added to questions where it does not help clarify the question at all.  But it is used for a few off-topic questions, and might seem to invite them:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740280/vulnerable-code-inspection-tools-for-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030213/free-tool-for-code-inspection-with-that-integrates-with-intellij-ide
- [Is there any tools for me to inspect which code is being ran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757321/is-there-any-tools-for-me-to-inspect-which-code-is-being-ran)
- [What is the difference between code reviews and code inspections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837507/what-is-the-difference-between-code-reviews-and-code-inspections)

Some of these are rather old questions, and thus might not have been off-topic when posted.  But it's my understanding that we don't invite such questions today.

Comment: You haven't adequately stated your case.  Most bad tags highlight a parade of bad questions; that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: While I've only identified four off-topic posts with this tag, that does represent nearly 10% of the questions.  And the other questions might as well not have the tag.  But indeed, it does not seem to be causing harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Robert Harvey's comment, I'd have to say that while the tag is perhaps not useful, it is also not harmful.  Thus there is no need to do anything about it.